# Comparing LSTM models using time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I have time series data (365 days) for 50 different stocks. I have fitted LSTM models for each stock to best predict price using the past three days of price data. I am using RMSE and R2 to evaluate the performance of each individual model. However, I want to statistically compare individual models against each other to understand why some models are underperforming compared to others. For example, I want to know whether the type of stock (i.e., raw materials, manufacturing, etc.) predicts model performance. Is there a specific statistical test I can use for this?

I tried to holistically compare contributing variables using SHAP values, but that doesn't provide the type of insight I am looking for-- i.e., whether some features of stocks (i.e., type) affect the model performance across LSTM models